# CSS bootstrap different positioning of multiple popovers

Tags: javascript, html, css, popover

I was wondering if it was possible to change the positioning of a popover each time it is called. I use them when I hover over a picture, and I have two pictures side by side, so if I set a margin for my first picture then the second popover will look too far. This is what i use to change the positioning.

```
popover.right{
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

[example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUZDu.png)
[example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7kcY.png)

As you can see 50px is too much and the popover appears farther right than the border of my menu. I would like to know if it is possible to change the positioning of my popovers each time they are created so they appear in the same vertical line.

here is some of the code: 
HTML:

```
<table>
                <tr>
                    <td><a rel="popover"  data-img="nuotraukos/cluemaps/Map_clue_McGrubors.png" ><div><img  class="mapFoto" src = "nuotraukos/cluemaps/Map_clue_McGrubors.png" onClick = "onClick(0,0)"></div></a></td>

                    <td><a rel="popover" data-img="nuotraukos/cluemaps/Map_clue_McGrubors.png" ><div><img  class="mapFoto" src = "nuotraukos/cluemaps/Map_clue_McGrubors.png" onClick = "onClick(15,15)"></div></a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><a rel="popover" data-img="nuotraukos/cluemaps/Map_clue_McGrubors.png" ><div><img  class="mapFoto" src = "nuotraukos/cluemaps/Map_clue_McGrubors.png" onClick = "onClick(0,0)"></div></a></td>

                    <td><a rel="popover" data-img="nuotraukos/cluemaps/Map_clue_McGrubors.png" ><div><img  class="mapFoto" src = "nuotraukos/cluemaps/Map_clue_McGrubors.png" onClick = "onClick(0,0)"></div></a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

JS:

```
$('a[rel=popover]').popover({
  html: true,
  trigger: 'hover',
  placement: 'right',
  content: function(){return '<img src="'+$(this).data('img') + '" style=\'width:100%\'  />';}
});
```

CSS:

```
.popover.right {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Comment: use css positioning... you missed to add your code to the question i guess

Comment: Yes this is definitely possible. Could you show us some of your code? The trick here will be using `position: relative` on the popovers, and positioning them relative to the items that trigger the popover.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to mention more parameters in the code . Check [this](http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/photo-galleries/css-popup-image.php) out for some more detailed info. about it
Here:[Link](http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/photo-galleries/css-popup-image.php)

Hope it help ;)

Comment: that's a great tutorial but it uses span to hide the object until hover while I use popover